# WpfToolkit AutoCompleteBox ContextMenu not working

Tags: c#, wpf, wpftoolkit

In one of my WPF project, I have integrated WPF Toolkit's `AutoCompleteBox` control. I need a custom `Context Menu` for this control and I have added one using the `ContextMenu` property. Unfortunately its not showing the custom created one but showing the default one (i.e. Cut, Copy, Paste with Cut & Copy as disabled).

To recreate the issue, I have created a sample project and the window contains 2 controls inside a `Grid`.

```
<Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <toolkit:AutoCompleteBox>
            <toolkit:AutoCompleteBox.ContextMenu>
                <ContextMenu>
                    <MenuItem Header="Menu Item 1"></MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem Header="Menu Item 2"></MenuItem>
                </ContextMenu>
            </toolkit:AutoCompleteBox.ContextMenu>
        </toolkit:AutoCompleteBox>
        <TextBox Grid.Row="1" >
            <TextBox.ContextMenu>
                <ContextMenu>
                    <MenuItem Header="Menu Item 1"></MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem Header="Menu Item 2"></MenuItem>
                </ContextMenu>
            </TextBox.ContextMenu>
        </TextBox>
    </Grid>
```

The two controls have the same `ContextMenu` and if I run the solution, I can see that the custom created `ContextMenu` is  working for `TextBox` and not for `AutoCompleteBox`.

Also, I set the same Context Menu to Grid (parent control) and set  `ContextMenu="{x:Null}"` to TextBox & `AutoCompleteBox`. Now the `ContextMenu` is inherited for `TextBox` but not for `AutoCompleteBox`.

So my question is, how can I create a custom `ContextMenu` for AutoCompleteBox? 
If it is not by design(`AutoCompleteBox`), how can I add a `ContextMenu` to a custom AutoCompleteBox control which is inherited from `AutoCompleteBox`. 
Please advice.

Comment: What do you want in your Context Menu? From what I'm seeing it is inheriting the Commands from the TextBox. Maybe you should implement your own.

Comment: @Dennis - Have you tried my answer? Doesn't it solve your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AutoCompleteBox` exposes `dependency property TextBoxStyle` which you can `set to customize TextBox hosted inside AutoCompleteBox`.

Another approach would be to provide your own template which i would strongly oppose since this DP is provide explicitly for the purpose you want i.e. to customize textBox from outside.

**Create a style for TextBox with your custom ContextMenu and apply that template both on your TextBox and AutoCompleteBox**. This sample is working fine -

```
<Grid>
   <Grid.Resources>
      <Style x:Key="CustomStyle" TargetType="TextBox"
             BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBox}}">
         <Setter Property="ContextMenu">
             <Setter.Value>
                <ContextMenu>
                    <MenuItem Header="Header1"/>
                    <MenuItem Header="Header2"/>
                 </ContextMenu>
             </Setter.Value>
         </Setter>
      </Style>
   </Grid.Resources>
   <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition/>
      <RowDefinition/>
   </Grid.RowDefinitions>
   <toolkit:AutoCompleteBox TextBoxStyle="{StaticResource CustomStyle}"/>
   <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Style="{StaticResource CustomStyle}"/>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue with Toolkits AutoCompleteBox is, they have missed to pass the ContextMenu to the inner elements of its visual tree. I have edited the template of AutoCompleteBox. Its working fine when I add TemplateBinding between ContextMenu of AutoCompleteBox and ContextMenu of TextBox inside the template of AutoCompleteBox.

Please find the code fix:

```
  <Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="toolkit:AutoCompleteBox" x:Key="AutoCompleteBoxStyle">
            <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False" />
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="2" />
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                        <GradientStop Color="#FFA3AEB9" Offset="0" />
                        <GradientStop Color="#FF8399A9" Offset="0.375" />
                        <GradientStop Color="#FF718597" Offset="0.375" />
                        <GradientStop Color="#FF617584" Offset="1" />
                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFFFFFFF" />
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF000000" />
            <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="45" />
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="toolkit:AutoCompleteBox">
                        <Grid Opacity="{TemplateBinding Opacity}">
                            <!-- Fix for AutoCompleteBox ContextMenu - Added TemplateBinding between ContextMenu of Textbox inside template and control's ContextMenu  -->
                            <TextBox ContextMenu="{TemplateBinding ContextMenu}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" IsTabStop="True" x:Name="Text" Style="{TemplateBinding TextBoxStyle}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" Margin="0" />
                            <Border x:Name="ValidationErrorElement" Visibility="Collapsed" BorderBrush="#FFDB000C" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="1">
                                <ToolTipService.ToolTip>
                                    <ToolTip x:Name="validationTooltip" DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Template="{DynamicResource CommonValidationToolTipTemplate}" Placement="Right" PlacementTarget="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}">
                                        <ToolTip.Triggers>
                                            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Canvas.Loaded">
                                                <BeginStoryboard>
                                                    <Storyboard>
                                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="validationTooltip" Storyboard.TargetProperty="IsHitTestVisible">
                                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                                    <sys:Boolean>true</sys:Boolean>
                                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                    </Storyboard>
                                                </BeginStoryboard>
                                            </EventTrigger>
                                        </ToolTip.Triggers>
                                    </ToolTip>
                                </ToolTipService.ToolTip>
                                <Grid Height="12" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="1,-4,-4,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="12" Background="Transparent">
                                    <Path Fill="#FFDC000C" Margin="1,3,0,0" Data="M 1,0 L6,0 A 2,2 90 0 1 8,2 L8,7 z" />
                                    <Path Fill="#ffffff" Margin="1,3,0,0" Data="M 0,0 L2,0 L 8,6 L8,8" />
                                </Grid>
                            </Border>
                            <Popup x:Name="Popup">
                                <Grid Opacity="{TemplateBinding Opacity}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" >
                                    <Border x:Name="PopupBorder" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Opacity="0" BorderThickness="0">
                                        <Border.RenderTransform>
                                            <TranslateTransform X="1" Y="1" />
                                        </Border.RenderTransform>
                                        <Border.Background>
                                            <SolidColorBrush Color="#11000000" />
                                        </Border.Background>
                                        <Border HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Opacity="1.0" Padding="0" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" CornerRadius="0">
                                            <Border.RenderTransform>
                                                <TransformGroup>
                                                    <TranslateTransform X="-1" Y="-1" />
                                                </TransformGroup>
                                            </Border.RenderTransform>
                                            <Border.Background>
                                                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                                    <GradientStop Color="#FFDDDDDD" Offset="0" />
                                                    <GradientStop Color="#AADDDDDD" Offset="1" />
                                                </LinearGradientBrush>
                                            </Border.Background>
                                            <ListBox x:Name="Selector" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ItemContainerStyle="{TemplateBinding ItemContainerStyle}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" BorderThickness="0" ItemTemplate="{TemplateBinding ItemTemplate}" />
                                        </Border>
                                    </Border>
                                </Grid>
                            </Popup>
                            <vsm:VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                <vsm:VisualStateGroup x:Name="PopupStates">
                                    <vsm:VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                        <vsm:VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.1" To="PopupOpened" />
                                        <vsm:VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.2" To="PopupClosed" />
                                    </vsm:VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                    <vsm:VisualState x:Name="PopupOpened">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="PopupBorder" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="1.0" Duration="0:0:0.1" />
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </vsm:VisualState>
                                    <vsm:VisualState x:Name="PopupClosed">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="PopupBorder" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="0" Duration="0:0:0.2" />
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </vsm:VisualState>
                                </vsm:VisualStateGroup>
                                <vsm:VisualStateGroup x:Name="ValidationStates">
                                    <vsm:VisualState x:Name="Valid" />
                                    <vsm:VisualState>
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ValidationErrorElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                        <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </vsm:VisualState>
                                    <vsm:VisualState x:Name="InvalidFocused">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ValidationErrorElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                        <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="validationTooltip" Storyboard.TargetProperty="IsOpen">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                        <sys:Boolean>True</sys:Boolean>
                                                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </vsm:VisualState>
                                </vsm:VisualStateGroup>
                            </vsm:VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <toolkit:AutoCompleteBox Style="{DynamicResource AutoCompleteBoxStyle}">
        <toolkit:AutoCompleteBox.ContextMenu>
            <ContextMenu>
                <MenuItem Header="Menu Item 1"></MenuItem>
                <MenuItem Header="Menu Item 2"></MenuItem>
            </ContextMenu>
        </toolkit:AutoCompleteBox.ContextMenu>
    </toolkit:AutoCompleteBox>
    <TextBox Grid.Row="1" >
        <TextBox.ContextMenu>
            <ContextMenu>
                <MenuItem Header="Menu Item 1"></MenuItem>
                <MenuItem Header="Menu Item 2"></MenuItem>
            </ContextMenu>
        </TextBox.ContextMenu>
    </TextBox>
</Grid>
```

Regards,
Abdul Rahman A.H.